# Add new item and properties with Generics and a Binding List

Tags: c#, generics

I have some code that calls a function. That function uses generics and should add a new item to a binding list.

For simplicity, I stripped down the code to show what I am trying to do.

Call a function to add an item to a BindingList called bookToc (type of class BookToc):

```
private CallingFunction()
{
    AddFunction(bookToc, typeof(BookToc).GetProperty(nameof(BookToc.BookTocItem)))
}
```

The function uses generics and should add a new item to the BindingList. Here is what I want the code to do (but it does not work):

```
public AddFunction<T>(BindingList<T> bindingList, PropertyInfo propertyName)
{
    string theItem = "Hello";
    string theTitle = "World";

    //this does not work because the generic list does not know the properties available:
    bindingList.Add(new BindingList
    {
        BookTocItem = theItem,
        BookTocTitle = theTitle
    });
}
```

Since I am using generics, I cannot seem to add a new item and set specific properties. I am sure the reason this is the case is because it is generic and therefore would not know the available properties.

I need to add a new row to a binding list and set specific properties using generics. Is this possible? If so, I would greatly appreciate a code sample.

Comment: But what values do you want to set the properties of the new element added to  the BindingList?. If you expect that your AddFunction is able to add a new element to the BindingList you need to pass also the values for each property you want to set in the new element. It doesn't seem to worth the effort

Comment: I did not place all the code for my solution in here because it is much more complex than this simple example. In the case of AddFunction, I want it to be able to add a new row to the BindingLIst called bookToc and place values in the BookTocItem and BookTocTitle properties. I cannot pass the values to AddFunction because AddFunction defines the values.

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do with `propertyName`? Why can't the caller set that property itself? `AddFunction` seems to be doing too much - it's both a factory method and it adds items to a given collection. Why not let the caller do the adding (`bookToc.Add(CreateFunction(...));`)? Are you certain that using *generics* is useful here, given that you need to work with *specific* properties?

Answer (score 1):

Add a type constraint in the function definition which tells the compiler what properties are available to T. Note the where clause below.

```
public Interface IBindingListItem {
   string BookTocItem {get; set;}
   string BookTocTitle {get; set}
}

public AddFunction<T>(BindingList<T> bindingList, PropertyInfo propertyName) where T: IBindingListItem, new()
{
   string theItem = "Hello";
   string theTitle = "World";

    //this does not work because the generic list does not know the properties available:
    bindingList.Add(new T
    {
       BookTocItem = theItem,
       BookTocTitle = theLinkGuid
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'd also add a `new()` constraint on `T` and replace `new BindingListItem` with `new T`.

Comment: BindlingListItem is just an example here. Howerver new T() might not work since there is no guarantee that the runtime type of T has a default constructor

Comment: That's what the `new()` constraint is for.

Comment: yes, that what T new is for.  What I was saying is the underlying impl. might not have a default constructor. So this new T constraint could be too strict.

Comment: Given that `bindingList.Add` takes a `T`, `new BindingListItem` wouldn't work anyway. If the OP wants to use a generic method he either needs that `new()` constraint or he needs to provide a `T` instance as an argument. Hard to tell which approach is better without knowing more about the context in which it's going to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I accepted it and updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Is there a way to do this to keep it purely generic? For example, I may want to pass over any BindingList and any property.